# Lua- Remote Event not firing

Tags: lua, roblox

In the script below the RemoteEvent is meant to fire when the health is less than 0 but on the client side it never receives the event. The first script is from the server side and it fires when a tool broadcasts the "mine" event. The target and v variables are what the player clicked on and is damaging. It is located inside ServerScriptService.

```
local collectables = workspace.MainFolder.Collectables
local DeafultHealth = 125
local HealthPerClick = 5

local COLORS = {
    { health = 90, color = Color3.fromRGB(0, 255, 0)},
    { health = 80, color = Color3.fromRGB(150, 255, 0)},
    { health = 70, color = Color3.fromRGB(200, 255, 0)},
    { health = 60, color = Color3.fromRGB(230, 255, 0)},
    { health = 50, color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 0)},
    { health = 40, color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 200, 0)},
    { health = 30, color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 150, 0)},
    { health = 20, color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 100, 0)},
    { health = 10, color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 50, 0)},
    { health = 0, color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0)},
}

for i, v in pairs(collectables:GetChildren()) do
    local bar = v.BillboardGui.Bar
    local health = v.Health
    health.Value = DeafultHealth
    bar.Parent.Enabled = false

    game.ReplicatedStorage.Mine.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, target, healthAmount)
        if v.Name == target.Name then
            local position = target.Position
            bar.Parent.Enabled = true
            for i = 1, healthAmount do
                health.Value -= healthAmount/healthAmount
                local barColor = bar.BackgroundColor3
                for i = 1, #COLORS do
                    if health.Value >= COLORS[i].health then
                        barColor = COLORS[i].color
                        break
                    end
                end
                bar.BackgroundColor3 = barColor
                if collectables:FindFirstChild(tostring(target)) then
                    bar:TweenSize(UDim2.new(health.Value/DeafultHealth * 0.9,0,0.3,0),'Out','Sine',0.5,true)
                end
                if health.Value < 0 then
                    game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Drop"):FireClient(player,target)
                    print(2)
                end
            end
        elseif healthAmount == 0 then
            print(2)
            game.ReplicatedStorage.Drop:FireClient(player,target)
            v:Destroy()
        end
    end)
end
```

The part I am having an issue with is firing the drop remote event. The 2 prints, but the client doesn't receive the event. The script below is run from the client and handles the inventory system. I only included the part that is having errors. That script is located inside StarterGui.

```
game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Drop").OnClientEvent:Connect(function(player)
    print("Fired")
end)
```

The "Fired" never prints.

Comment: I updated my post with more information on what the scripts are and where they are located.

Comment: There still isn't any information about what you are passing to the Mine event when you call `game.ReplicatedStorage.Mine:FireServer(?, ?)`. What is `target` and `healthAmount`?

Comment: 'target is the item in the workspace that the player clicked on with the tool, and 'healthAmount' is the amount of health to remove from the target.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying to which player the RemoteEvent should be fired to. You're only sending the target.
Perhaps you should try this instead:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.Drop:FireClient(player, target)
```

Comment: That part of the script isn't firing because of the amount of health I set the item to have, but I tried it anyway and it didn't work.

Comment: It's possible the LocalScript is not positioned somewhere it can run in. Where is it located? If the 2 prints then the problem is the LocalScript or something related with it.

Comment: It is located inside StarterGui. I updated my original post with more information if you need it.

Comment: Have you perhaps tried printing something after you connect the OnClientEvent? So you can see if the code isn't broken and it actually connects the event.

Comment: I got the script working. I think it wasn't working because I had it after a 'while wait() do' loop and I moved it before.